# loadUrl is not working in electron

Tags: electron

i am new to electron.

### i tried to run the index.js with following lines, it worked

```
const electron = require("electron")
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
var mainWindow = null

app.on('ready', function () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
})
```

---

but when i tried to add this line,

```
mainWindow.loadUrl('file://${ __dirname}/index.html')
```

it return an error "typeError:mainWindow.loadUrl is not a function"

i searched a lot for the answer, but didnt get any answer for this.

can any suggest a solution for this?
any help will be appreciated

Comment: When you tried to add that line where?

Comment: const electron = require("electron")
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
var mainWindow = null

app.on('ready', function () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://${ __dirname}/index.html')
})

Comment: thanks Evan Trimboli for your reply

Comment: add that line after,   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

Comment: the electron window is loading. but it says "A javascript error occurred in the main process. uncaught exception: TypeError:mainWindow.loadUrl is not a function"

Comment: Evan, Is there any solution for this

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`loadUrl()` was renamed to `loadURL()` a while back.

Comment: Great. Now the error gone. thanks @Vadim Macagon. But the window is not showing the index.html content.

Comment: I dont know how, now index.html's content is loading. Anyway Thanks Vadim Macagon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mainWindow.loadFile('${ __dirname}/index.html')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it by using backticks instead of single quotes. The prettier extension kept changing them back to single quotes.

Before:

```
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://${__dirname}/index.html')
```

After:

```
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
```